# Django Class Based UpdateView does not make any changes/Update the model it is called on

Tags: python, django

I have just started learning Django and was trying to create a simple blog website, but for some reason, I am unable to update my blog though UpdateView. Every time I hit the submit button from the update blog page, it takes me back to the detail view page without making any changes. Apart from UpdateView, rest seems to work fine like CreateView, DeleteView, ListView.

Here is the code for views.py-

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post.html'
    context_object_name = 'obj'
    form = CommentForm

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            PostView.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user,post=obj)
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        CatCount = Category_Count()
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['latest'] = Post.objects.order_by('-date_added')[0:3]
        context['Category_Count'] = CatCount
        context['form'] = self.form
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = self.get_object()
            form.instance.Author = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect('post', pk=post.pk)
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

```py
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    success_url ="/"

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            PostView.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user,post=obj)
        return obj
    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post=self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.Author:
            return True
        return False
```

```py
class PostDeleteView( LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url='/'

    def test_func(self):
        post=self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.Author:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

```py
class PostCreateView( LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/Create.html'
    form_class = PostForm 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.Author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here is the form, I am using in UpdateView -

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCEWidget(
            attrs={'required': False, 'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}
        ))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields= ['title', 'thumbnail', 'Content','Categories', 'featured']
```

Here is the template for UpdateView-

```
{%  extends 'posts/base.html'  %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<div class='col-100 offset-1 mb-6 mt-4'>  <h3> Update </h3>
</div>
<div class='col-4 offset-2 mb-5 mt-5'>
  {{form.media}}
  <form method ='POST' action ='.' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form|crispy}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>
    
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Here is the link to the project, just in case- https://github.com/k-ken-source/DailyBlog-/blob/master/posts/views.py

I have no idea what am I doing wrong, so any hint would be highly appreciated. ThankYou in advance.

Comment: What error, etc. do you receive. Are you sure you make a POST request, and trigger the `UpdateView`?

Comment: first of all fix indentation, also provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, I am sorry about the bad indentation and have fixed it. I have also added the template for UpdateView and @Willem Van Onsem, as you can see I am making a POST request., So that does not seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found out, that the problem lies in your template `post_form.html`:

```html
<form method='POST' action='.'></form>
```

Here the `action='.'` causes you the trouble. This advises the browser to send the data to a different URL, but you need to send the data to the URL of your `UpdateView`.

Remove this attribute and it works like intended.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help and yes that seems to be the issue. It's working fine now.